# Why do these 2 (similar?) MySQL queries vary so much in their execution times?

Tags: mysql, select, indexing

I have the tables `players`, `players_to_teams`, and `accounts`.  `players_to_teams` has a FK to `players` and `accounts`.  `players` has a `FirstName` and `accounts` has a `Name`. Both `FirstName` and `Name` are indexed.

Running

```
SELECT players_to_teams.id
FROM players_to_teams
INNER JOIN players
ON players.id = players_to_teams.player_id
ORDER BY players.FirstName
```

executes in 0.004 seconds.

```
SELECT players_to_teams.id
FROM players_to_teams
INNER JOIN accounts
ON accounts.id = players_to_teams.account_id
ORDER BY accounts.Name
```

executes in over 7 seconds.

There are 30,000 account records and 250k player records.

`EXPLAIN`s can be found here: https://gist.github.com/2368906

Shouldn't these queries execute in similar time spaces?

Comment: how many accounts do you have ?

Comment: It has something to do with the amount of columns or records (I don't remember) that the joining tables have. I remember seeing that concept in a database class a while ago. Let me refresh my mind.

Comment: maybe account_id in palyers to teams is not indexed?

Comment: @Rufinus - I had a typo.  I have 30,000 account records

Comment: @kappa - account_id is indexed in players_to_team (I think).  Can you double check on that gist?

Comment: so it was the Name field in order by not well indexed

Comment: @kappa What do you mean?

Comment: when doing an ORDER BY if the field using to sort is not indexed, time grows up a lot

Comment: @kappa `accounts.Name` is indexed.  I don't need to do something special, do I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your slower query needs a temporary table to sort the result set, while the other one can use the index on FirstName, avoiding the sorting all together. (Extra: Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort)

Can you try forcing the index on accounts to see if you can outsmart the optimized?

```
SELECT players_to_teams.id
FROM players_to_teams 
INNER JOIN accounts FORCE INDEX(Name)
ON accounts.id = players_to_teams.account_id
ORDER BY accounts.Name
```

Another alternative would be to rewrite the query with a straight join, and have the accounts table listed first.

I don't have any good answer as to why it currently picks players_to_teams first when accounts has way less rows.

Comment: A straight join will force MySQL to use the tables in the order you've specified. [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html)

Comment: `STRAIGHT_JOIN` didn't work.  Amazing that the index is just skipped over

Answer (score 1):

One other option that might help... that I remember reading somewhere...  If you have an index on both the account ID and Name as a single index (id, name), then the engine does not have to go back to the raw data records to extract the name value and can pull it directly from the index... thus saving time from a full record read on the matches.

Comment: `accounts` has the `id_name` compound index.  Is that what you were thinking?